# Mac OSX Sierra Play 2.5 Https Localhost - This site can’t provide a secure connection

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, https, playframework-2.5

I am not able to run Java Play 2.5 application locally.I am using Mac OSX Sierra, before I was using Windows 10 and had no problems. If I try to use application through https://localhost:9000 I always receive error in chrome:

his site can’t provide a secure connection

On Mozilla:

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:9000. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Safari:

safari cant open the page because Safari cant establish secure connection to the server.

I am sure there is an issue with autogenerated self signed certificated by Play but I do not know how to solve it...

I tried http and it works, but my application forces https.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://localhost:9000

I doubt you are set up to use HTTPS locally

Comment: Further note: to force HTTPS only in production, use specific application.conf file. Check [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration) for details.